# How to handle special characters in SQL Server fulltext search?

Tags: sql-server, special-characters, full-text-search

I've made an AJAX search that calls a fulltext search on a SQL Server database. It works well with regular characters, but if I input certain special characters like `&` and `|`, I get a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` and the error

> Syntax error near '' in the full-text search condition

What's the best way to handle this? Should I escape the input string server-side (C#) or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: How does your C# code look like?